# laravel API, not fetching data from DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

This is on production side (on unbtu Digital Ocean server)

- "laravel: 5.3"
- "php": "5.5.9"

Route path : /route/web.php (not in middleware)

```
Route::get('api/getsymbol-request','MemberTradesController@getSymbolRequest');
Route::get('api/getsymbol','MemberTradesController@getSymbol');
```

Controller:

```
public function getSymbolRequest(Request $request){
        $symbol = DB::table("symbols")
            ->where("market_id", $request->market_id)
            ->pluck("symbol","id");
        return response() -> json($symbol);
    }

public function getSymbol(){
        $symbol = DB::table("symbols")
            ->pluck("symbol","id");
        return response() -> json($symbol);
    }
```

http://yourtradelog.com/api/getsymbol-request?market_id=1       //This is *not working url* I am getting issue **WHY THIS IS NOT WORKING**

http://yourtradelog.com/api/getsymbol                         //This is working url

[Database tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwbgG.png)

```js
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#exchange').change(function(){
                var exchangeID = $(this).val();
                if(exchangeID){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                        url:"{{url('api/getsymbol-request/')}}?exchange_id="+exchangeID,
                        success:function(res){
                            if(res){
                                $("#market").empty();
                                $("#market").append('<option>Select</option>');
                                $.each(res,function(key,value){
                                    $("#market").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                                });

                            }else{
                                $("#market").empty();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    $("#market").empty();
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

```html
     {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> 'MemberTradesController@store']) !!}
 <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                {!! Form::label('market_id', 'Markets:') !!}
                {!! Form::select('market_id', [''=>'Choose Options'] , null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'market'])!!}
            </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-10">
            {!! Form::label('symbol_id', 'Symbol:') !!}
            {!! Form::select('symbol_id', [''=>'Choose Options'] ,  null, ['class'=>'symbol_id', 'id'=>'symbol','data-width'=>'60%', 'data-live-search'=>'true'] )!!}
        </div>
 
 <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                {!! Form::submit('Add trade', ['class'=>'btn btn-success btn-lg']) !!}
            </div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: post your routes

Comment: route is posted @AdnanMumtaz

Comment: your both urls are working fine. maybe you dont have data in your db

Comment: see screen shot of DB, there is data in DB @AdnanMumtaz

Comment: either you dont have data in your db or `where` condition matched empty result

Comment: try `$symbol = DB::table("symbols")
            ->where("market_id", $request->market_id)
            ->get()->pluck("symbol","id");`

Comment: I have uploaded my DB table also.. there is not empty & where condition have 1 which is also matched with 'market_id' = 1

Comment: put this line in your `getSymbolRequest()` function: `dd($request->all())` and post the output here.

Comment: Why don't you use this format instead? `Route::get('api/getsymbol-request/{id}','MemberTradesController@getSymbolRequest');` and then `public function getSymbolRequest(Request $request, $id)`

Comment: can you make for me this function $id route ... i want to try this if it work... @BálintBudavölgyi   can you write **Function** also for me please...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer using route parameters like this (see more in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing)):

Routes:

```
Route::get('api/getsymbol-request/{id}','MemberTradesController@getSymbolRequest');
Route::get('api/getsymbol','MemberTradesController@getSymbol');
```

Controller:

```
public function getSymbolRequest(Request $request, $id){
        $symbol = DB::table("symbols")
            ->where("market_id", $id)
            ->get()
            ->pluck("symbol","id");
        return response() -> json($symbol);
    }

public function getSymbol(){
        $symbol = DB::table("symbols")
            ->pluck("symbol","id");
        return response() -> json($symbol);
    }
```

> Please note that the URL has changed to this format:
>
> http://yourtradelog.com/api/getsymbol-request/1

Comment: this is worked for me... but i dont why my code not worked.... well its good work for me. thank you so much. i dont have enough credit score otherwise i hit it up.

Comment: Thanks, you can mark my answer correct as well, if you think it is. I assume you did no get the parameters through the URL, but you can check if you put this line in your `getSymbolRequest()` function (having the previous route of course): `dd($request->all())`

Comment: @ Bálint Budavölgyi   is this ok url for ajax :      $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:  "{{url('api/getsymbol-request')}}?market_id="+$id,

Comment: With the new route format it should be like this: `$.ajax({ type:"GET", url: "{{url('api/getsymbol-request/')}}"+$id`

Comment: http://yourtradelog.com/api/getsymbol-request/{id} if use this url in ajax then, it also not worked.. let me paste here ajax

Comment: Your URL is missing a `/`

Comment: Please add the ajax code to your question, not to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to this code:

```
public function getSymbolRequest(Request $request)
{
    $marketID = (int)$request->get('market_id')
    $symbol = DB::table('symbols')
        ->where('market_id', $marketID)
        ->get(['symbol','id']);
    return response()->json($symbol);
}
public function getSymbol()
{
    $symbol = DB::table('symbols')
        ->get(['symbol','id']);
    return response()->json($symbol);
}
```

Comment: $marketID = (int)$request->get('market_id') // Add data type worked for me when I am using MongoDB